# Strapi + Cloud SQL for MySQL on Google App Engine - Server wasn't able to start properly Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, strapi

I'm trying to start my Strapi app into Google App Engine, I did deployed successfully, but I keep getting this error on the logs:

> Server wasn't able to start properly
> Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN /cloudsql/connectionName

Error Log:

[image: error logs]

I followed the instructions of deployment, but maybe something is missing, is like my app can't establish the connection with my Cloud SQL for MySQL database.

This is my .yaml file:

```js
runtime: nodejs12

instance_class: F2

env_variables:
  HOST: '0.0.0.0'
  NODE_ENV: 'production'
  DATABASE_NAME: 'test'
  DATABASE_USERNAME: '***'
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: '***'
  INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: '***'

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: '***'
```

```js
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: 'default',
  connections: {
    default: {
      connector: 'bookshelf',
      settings: {
        client: 'mysql',
        host: `/cloudsql/${env('INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME')}`,
        database: env('DATABASE_NAME'),
        username: env('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
        password: env('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

If someone knows about this and can help me I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After reviewing their official [docs](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations.html#server) and GitHub [issue](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/1714), it turns out that what works properly when connecting via Unix Socket on Cloud SQL is to change `host` to `socketPath`, contrary to what's currently written which is `socket` (don't know why it doesn't). I tested and it works on v3.6.1.

After following their deployment guide, install mysql driver on your project:

```
yarn add mysql
```

Then, change `host` to `socketPath`:

```js
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: 'default',
  connections: {
    default: {
      connector: 'bookshelf',
      settings: {
        client: 'mysql',
        socketPath: `/cloudsql/${env('INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME')}`,
        database: env('DATABASE_NAME'),
        username: env('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
        password: env('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Then to manage your project, go to the administration panel at /admin of your GAE URL.

Comment: Thanks @Dondi, I just had to change `host` to `socketPath`.